# How to properly simulate mouse clicks for Unity games?

Tags: c++, windows, unity-game-engine, input, bots

I'm working on an autonomous bot for a [Unity](https://unity.com) game on Windows. For simulating clicks, I tried using the Windows API with [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) but it did nothing:

```
void click_with_send_message(HWND window_handle, POINT client_coordinates)
{
    const auto coordinates_parameter = MAKELPARAM(client_coordinates.x, client_coordinates.y);
    SendMessage(window_handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates_parameter);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    SendMessage(window_handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates_parameter);
}
```

Using [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) works but I would like clicks to be simulated *without* focusing the window and/or stealing the mouse. Also simulating clicks while the process is minimized would be even better. I noticed that I might want to hook/hijack some `Unity` functions so I found
[Input.GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html), [Input.GetMouseButtonUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) and [Input.get_mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html). I figured that simulating my desired mouse coordinates, a mouse down and a mouse up would do the trick but it did nothing once again. Also, while researching online, I did not find code examples or tutorials on how to do this for Unity games. Furthermore, [Unity seems to attach OnClick events onto objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html). Any ideas how to simulate input/clicks on Unity without using `SendInput()`? I'm working in C++ with an [injected DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection).

Comment: _"SendMessage()"_ - ya this one is not really recommended since Vista.  You could try _Microsoft UI Automation_ (UIA).  Though originally for remote controlling apps during _application testing_ it's common to use it as a general purpose replacement for `SendMessage()`.  Also, UIA even works with apps that have **no child controls** such as **WPF** which is a good example considering WPF uses DirectX to draw and blit the results in a single go.  When Microsoft designed WPF, they provided another means to fiddle with widgets and it just so happens UIA is compatible.  Unity is also DX.  :)

Comment: Failing that you might be able to use a Mouse Journal Proc and inject messages that way.

Comment: have you found answer to that question? I am currently doing the same

Comment: @LOST: Well, I made some progress by hooking a function which indicates whether the game is focused and made it always return true, then I could use e.g. `SendMessage()` again and it worked while the game is in the background but not in all cases sadly, some clicks still didn't register.

Comment: Which function did you have to hook? I tried hooking `GetForegroundWindow` to no avail

Comment: @LOST: It was `Application_get_isFocused` but your code may look differently